# How to use Fire php in a static class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use fire php inside a static class,

so how can i do

```
$this->firephp->log(323);
```

With static? I've tried

```
self::$firephp->log(323);
```

And also

```
 $obj =& get_instance();
 $obj->firephp->log(323);
```

But doesn't works.....

Thanks

Comment: How does this work. Does firephp automatically inject itself as a member of any class instance?

Comment: apokryfos - i'm not quite sure... when working with pure codeigniter - the yes - you only needs to load the library and use it as i mentioned ... problem is i'm working with an ionize-cms which is based on codeigniter....and all the classes are static....

Comment: Try the suggested code in [github](https://github.com/firephp/firephp/blob/master/docs/API/FirePHP.md) `$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);` and then `$firephp->log(...)`

Comment: Thanks - that's what i was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017, firebug and hence firephp has been disabled.

If I understand you, you intend to call static methods which is possible in ChromePhp - I think you might want to take a look at it

I wrote some little modifications to the chromephp tool to allow seamless migration from firephp to chromephp for debuging via the console.

This article explains in clear easy steps

https://medium.com/@kudehinbuoluwaponle/migrate-from-firephp-to-chromephp-in-5-minutes-without-breaking-existing-code-e4afd1b28c5c